# NSTimer Crash in ARC Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nstimer, invalidation

I have the following pair of functions in a MessagePlayerViewController(UIViewController) which move a slider to reflect playback progress of an AVAudioPlayer:

```
-(void)startTrackingPlayback
{
    if(!self.isPlaying)
    {
        self.isPlaying = YES;
        self.playbackTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

-(void)stopTrackingPlayback
{
    if(self.playbackTimer)
    {
        if(self.playbackTimer.isValid)
        {
            [self.playbackTimer invalidate];
            self.playbackTimer = nil;
        }
    }
    self.isPlaying = NO;
}
```

Intermittently, and following no discernible pattern, I get an `Exec Bad Access` ith the top two items in the stack as:

```
0 objc_msgSend
1 [MessagePlayerViewController stopTrackingPlayback];
```

How can this be? I check if the timer exists before I call `isValid` and I check `isValid` before I invalidate it.

Using a breakpoint I can see that the timer does exist, but the error occurs when I set it to nil. If I remove this line, I get an identical error on the line:

```
[self.playbackTimer invalidate];
```

Comment: what do you do in updateProgress? can you show?

Comment: please add all the methods that you have used.

Comment: Try using it with `... repeats:NO` and setting it again in the handler

Comment: Try accessing it as a local variable instead of self - eg. `_playbackTimer` instead of `self.playbackTimer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest inspecting the way you use your `MessagePlayerViewController`. It seems to me that both the stack trace and the behaviour you describe hint at the fact that it is the controller that is being deallocated earlier than your timer.

Take into account the fact that the run loop where the timer is scheduled will keep the timer alive.

Maybe the fix is as simple as calling `invalidate` in your controller's `dealloc` method (or somewhere else where it makes sense), but if you do not provide more code, it is not possible to say.

Comment: You were bang on the money. That was exactly the problem. I was not seeing the wood for the trees.